# Difference between `public` and `private` inheritance when inheriting from abstract classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding, abstract-class

I have a class `Placeable`:

```cpp
struct Placeable {
    virtual void place_at(int x, int y) const {}

    virtual ~Placeable() = default;
};
```

I also have several other types, such as `Box`, that inherit from `Placeable`, and override the function `place_at()`.

```cpp
struct Box : Placeable {  /* Private inheritance for now (by default) */
    void place_at(int x, int y) const override {
        /* ...Code... */
    }
};
```

As you can likely tell, I intend `Placeable` to be an abstract class, having only functions and no member variables, so as to specify the interfaces of inherited types. However, I'm unsure of **which type of inheritance I should use on `Box`** and other related types.

I've learned that in `public` inheritance, the members of the base class are accessible from derived classes, and that in `private` inheritance, they are not (I doubt `protected` inheritance is what I'm looking for here, so I've left it out. Let me know if I should be using that instead). However, because `Placeable` *has* no member variables, **is there any difference between `public` and `private` inheritance here**? When I run this testing code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Placeable {
    virtual void place_at(int x, int y) const {}

    virtual ~Placeable() = default;
};

struct Box : Placeable {  /* private by default, try changing to public */
    void place_at(int x, int y) const override {
        /* ...Code... */
    }
};

int main()
{
    Placeable *ptr = new Box();

    /* Calls `Box::place_at()` no matter the type of inheritance! */
    ptr->place_at(1, 2);

    delete ptr;

    return 0;
}
```

there seems to be no difference between `public` and `private` inheritance; `Box::place_at(1, 2)` is called for both `public` and `private` inheritance. Can someone explain what is going on to me? I must be missing something.

Comment: Your `place_at()` methods should be `public` or change the structure to a `struct` instead of a `class`.  The default accessibility for a `class` is `private` contents.  I suggest resolving this issue and turning up the warning and error levels (to maximum reporting).

Comment: Assigning a method to 0 makes a `class` or `struct` abstract.  For example, `virtual bool is_at(int x, int y) const = 0;`

Comment: @ThomasMatthews About your first comment, that was my mistake; I changed `class` to `struct` for both `Placeable` and `Box`. About your second comment, I've never heard about that - so does this *force* all derived classes to override `is_at`?

Comment: `struct Box : Placeable`  is `public inheritance` by default, not `private`

Comment: A good C++ reference should have a section discussing [abstract classes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/abstract_class).

Comment: With private inheritance `Placeable *ptr = new Box;` would fail because the base is not accessible.

Comment: You can't create an instance of an abstract `class` or `struct`.  What errors or warnings is your compiler generating?

Comment: I highly recommend not using default inheritance.  If you want private inheritance, then place the `private` keyword in the `inheritance` syntax.  Same with `public`.  This removes any ambiguities.

Comment: Overriding of virtual functions doesn’t depend on access. Same name and signature is all that matters.

Comment: Note that an abstract class is a class with at least one **pure virtual function**. It can have non-virtual functions and it can have data members. Your `Placeable` class would typically have `virtual void place_at(int, int) const =0;`. `place_at` doesn’t need any implementation. The `=0` says that it’s a pure virtual function.

Comment: My own convention is to put *interface* classes (which I do as `struct`, and constrain myself to having no member variables, a protected destructor, and pure virtual methods) in `namespace interface { /*...*/ }`.  (I do make the destructor `virtual`, even though protected, and have it be defined in a **cpp** file because the compiler will generate the virtual function table in that translation unit — which is my compiler's implementation detail.)

Comment: _"However, I'm unsure of which type of inheritance I should use on `Box` and other related types."_ — The rule of thumb is as follows: Public inheritance = _IS-A_ relationship. If `Box` is a `Placable`, use it. Private inheritance = _IMPLEMENTED-IN-TERMS-OF_ relationship.